# Conversion of my Project from Youtube data api to dailymotion api.

Tags: youtube-data-api, dailymotion-api

I have a complete source code of a project using you tube data API v3, when i try to publish my app its continuously rejected due to copyright issue. (i m using someone else channel link), 
here is what it says :-
I reviewed your app, and had to reject it because it violates our device and network abuse policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still live on Google Play.

Here’s how you can submit your app for another review:

```
Your app shouldn’t access or use a service or API in a manner that violates its terms of service. For example, make sure your app doesn’t download, monetize, or access YouTube videos in a way that violates the YouTube Terms of Service.
Read through the Device and Network Abuse policy for more details and examples.
```

now i want to change my code from You tube data API to daily motion API, and i need your help. 
Or if someone has any solution how can i get my app approved using someone Else's channel. ?

Comment: i have also tried to make my channel and uploaded few songs videos but it still got rejected.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what kind of questions work here. A better approach for you to get help here might be to attempt yourself and then ask specific programming questions which are on topic.

Comment: I think you are showing ads in your app. youtube+ admob = problem. I had same issue. I removed all ads and it got published on play store. Also make sure your app doesn't play video in background.